# Generic Class Lists used with Strategy Pattern

Tags: c#, asp.net, generics, dependency-injection, strategy-pattern

I want to use generic classes with strategy pattern along with dependency injection in Asp.net

*Definition of interface and concrete class*

```c#
public interface IPaymentMethod<T> 
{
   string Name { get; set }
}

public interface PaymentMethod<T> : IPaymentMethod<T> where T: class 
{ 
   public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

*Startup.cs*

```c#
services.AddScoped(typeof(IPaymentMethod<>), typeof(PaymentMethod<>));
```

*In the application*

```c#
public class PaymentResolver 
{
    public PaymentResolver(List<IPaymentMethod<????>> paymentMethods) 
    { ... }

    public IPaymentMethod Resolve(string name)
    {
        return _paymentMethods.FirstOrDefault(item => item.Name == name);
    }
}
```

How can I get the collection of IPaymentMethod instances from the dependency injection? PaymentResolver.Resolve method doesn't seem to be correct.

Comment: You can't have a list of generic types, even with DI out of the equation.

Comment: What is `T` in `IPaymentMethod<T>` stand for? Please update your question with more information about your design. What is `T`? Why do you need it? How do you use it?

Comment: Steven, it's more of learning how to use generic class lists with strategy pattern less than the context of the example. T could represent anything, not bound to this basic example

Comment: You have no concrete class. Both `IPaymentMethod` and `PaymentMethod` are marked as interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is kind of conflict to your self. So basically, you want to get a service when you know the service name. Then, my question is if you know service name

```
_paymentResolver.GetPaymentMethod("CreditCard/DebitCard")
```

you must know service type as well

```
class Invoice
{
 public Invoice(IPaymentMethod<CreditCard> cc, IPaymentMethod<DeditCard> dc) {}
}
```

So what stops you from using a type rather than a name? Not to mention that it offers you strongly type so you don't have a risk of mistype the name.

Hope this helps clear your mind.

Comment: Yes it's doable in this way but could be difficult to manage if you have dozens types of IPaymentMethod whereas the collection is easier. It seems no way of doing it that way

Comment: Hi @Melih, that's true. However, there is a way to make the code a bit better. If you can use Aggregate Service from Autofac (https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/aggregate-services.html). You can group all allowed payment services into 1 service.
.net core doesn't have this yet, but you can easily replicate this feature.